# How to add a simple ad banner along a webview (phonegap) in android

Tags: android, android-layout, cordova, ads, startapp

I'm trying since yersterday afternoon non stop to add a simple banner ad to my app wich is created with phonegap 3.3.
Im a beginner in android and I dont know how to make the main layout so that it includes both: the phonegap view and the banner.
I followed this tutotial becaus eit describer a more easyer way to add the banner without unsing .xml:
https://support.startapp.com/entries/27804376-Adding-a-banner-with-Java-Code-instead-of-XML
Right now I see the ad on a black background but the phonegap view isn't showing. How to add the phonegap view too?

mainlayout.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/
</RelativeLayout>
```

whatsnap.java:

```
public class WhatSnap extends CordovaActivity 
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.init();
        StartAppSDK.init(this, "id", "id");
//        StartAppAd.showSplash(this, savedInstanceState);
//        StartAppAd.showSlider(this);
        // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
        super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl());
        appView.addJavascriptInterface(this, "WhatSnap");
        //super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html")  
        setContentView(R.layout.mainlayout);

     // Get the Main relative layout of the entire activity
        RelativeLayout mainlayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainlayout);   
       // Define StartApp Banner
        Banner startAppBanner = new Banner(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams bannerParameters =
                    new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        bannerParameters.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        bannerParameters.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);    
      // Add to main Layout
        mainlayout.addView(startAppBanner, bannerParameters);
    }
}
```

I also tried ti implement the ad the .xml way by addingthis to my main layout:

```
<com.startapp.android.publish.banner.Banner 
          android:id="@+id/startAppBanner"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
```

so my layout is like this:

But it still show me just the add on a black background and the phonegap webview isn't showing.

I tried another way by first implementing the phonegap webview and adding the banner code in the new created layout:

Whatsnap.java:
public class WhatSnap extends CordovaActivity

```
{
    CordovaWebView cwv;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        cwv = (CordovaWebView) findViewById(R.id.tutorialView);
        Config.init(this);
        StartAppSDK.init(this, "id", "id");
        super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl());
        appView.addJavascriptInterface(this, "WhatSnap");
    }
}
    @Override
    public ExecutorService getThreadPool() {
        return getThreadPool();
    }
```

main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView
    android:id="@+id/tutorialView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<com.startapp.android.publish.banner.Banner 
          android:id="@+id/startAppBanner"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now the phonegap webview is showing but the ad banner no :(

********EDIT:
Im trying for 2 days to implement a simple ad banner into my ap. For that I followed the instructions to implement phonegap as a webview from here: 
docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/… 
and I also included the needed banner code into my main layout:

```
<com.startapp.android.publish.banner.Banner 
android:id="@+id/startAppBanner" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
```

everythings shows up good but after including phonegap as a webview (in the 1 step) the pause and resume events stop working from phonegap and I get these lines in logcat:

```
07-10 12:10:10.368: D/CordovaActivity(20511): Paused the application! 
07-10 12:10:10.368: D/CordovaWebView(20511): Handle the pause 
07-10 12:10:10.378: D/CordovaLog(20511): null: Line 1 : exception firing resume event from native 
07-10 12:10:10.378: I/Web Console(20511): exception firing resume event from native at null:1 
07-10 12:10:10.383: D/CordovaLog(20511): null: Line 1 : exception firing pause event from native 
07-10 12:10:10.383: I/Web Console(20511): exception firing pause event from native at null:1 
07-10 12:10:10.483: E/JavaBinder(20511): !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
```

This is my main activity:

```
public class WhatSnap extends CordovaActivity 
{ 
CordovaWebView cwv; 
@Override 
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{ 
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
super.init(); 
StartAppSDK.init(this, "id", "id"); 
appView.addJavascriptInterface(this, "WhatSnap"); 

setContentView(R.layout.main); 
cwv = (CordovaWebView) findViewById(R.id.tutorialView); 
Config.init(this); 
cwv.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl()); 
} 

@Override 
public ExecutorService getThreadPool() { 
return getThreadPool(); 
}
```

this is my layout so far:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:baselineAligned="false"> 


<org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView 
android:id="@+id/tutorialView" 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="match_parent" /> 


<com.startapp.android.publish.banner.Banner 
android:id="@+id/startAppBanner" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/> 

</RelativeLayout>
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

I tried to show ads in screen, And this will display ads in footer which you are trying.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView
        android:id="@+id/tutorialView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <com.startapp.android.publish.banner.Banner
        android:id="@+id/startAppBanner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Let me know any issues in ads are not being loaded in view or anything else.